# Is there a way to call a function multiple times on the reference it returns programmatically? -Tuple Dynamic access

Tags: c++, recursion, dynamic, tuples

Out of interest I am trying to implement a variadic template tuple type with dynamic access and I would like to avoid casts and returning `boost::any` or `boost::variant`. I have come to the point were every recursive inheritance stores a pointer to itself and I am able to return it like so:

```
ParentType& next() {
    return *this;
}
```

I can call this when I write in source and iterate like so for example:

```
MyTupleImpl<int, std::string, float> myTuple;
myTuple.next().next().next();
```

which returns a

```
 MyTupleImpl<float> &
```

I can then do some operations on the data held by this Tuple like so:

```
 void DoSomething( myTuple.next().next().next().data);
```

I can write this down in source, but how could I implement it such that I just pass a number n and it applies the function `next()` n times on its returned reference.

I tried recursion along the lines of:

```
ParentType* get(int i, int j, OwnType k) {

    std::cout << "j" << j << "i" << i << std::endl;
    if (j < i) {
        j++;
        return k.next().get(i, j, k.next());
    }
    else
    {
        return k.current;
    }
}
```

As is relatively obvious there is always a conflict with the return type of the function since the context in which its called like so:

```
myTuple.get(1,0,myTuple);
```

has its `ParentType` set but when next is called `ParentType` changes.

I can imagine that return Type deduction is one of the reasons why tuples can not be dynamically accessed. However why does the this work programmatically when I call in source.

```
myTuple.next().next();
```

for example.

I know this is somewhat confused however I hope some of you will understand what I mean and be able to help me. I apologize as I am somewhat of a Novice when it comes to C++ and templated classes.

Comment: As I am new to posting to stackoverflow I would also appreciate criticism on the way i post/ask questions, like choice of title and tags etc. and if the way this is posted is acceptable. Thanks.

Comment: Your `get` should be template (to take constexpr index). as `std::get<I>(tuple)` does.

Comment: any reason why you can't just use std::get?

Comment: because i can not pass an index at runtime as far as i understand. Furthermore im implementing my own tuple that does ( i assume ) not meet the requirements to use std::get.

Comment: I would like to avoid adding a template parameter to my get implementation as i have to have it at compile time.

Comment: return type of the function cannot depend of runtime value.

Comment: `myTuple.next().next();` works because what would be `i` is fixed at compile-time to be `2`. Once you shift it to runtime, you have to deal with the fact that you don't know the return type anymore. This could be something like what `boost::variant` visitors do -- generate a jump table, and dispatch to a user-provided overloaded function.

Comment: I understand. However when i write the next() function consecutively, i return a reference to another tuple type and then apply next to that one is something like this possible programatically? I see that writing 3 times next is similar if not the same to passing a template parameter const index 3, however the procedure that it is achieved with seems different to me and lets me hope that something like call next i times is somehow possible.

Comment: I just read your comment Quentin after posting. In your opinion would you say what i'm envisaging is even possible?

Comment: @BafE. The return type of `next()` may change for each previous `next()`. For example, `myTuple.next()` might not have the same type as `myTuple.next().next()`. Because all return types must be known at compile time, the number of consecutive `next()` must be known as well.

Comment: Thanks to all the fast commenters by the way. I am a little surprised by the speed but very gratefull for your help.

Comment: Is there a data structure in c++, that resembles a tuple, with dynamic access? If yes is it possible to point me somewhere to read up on it, I would be very interested in how they solved that ?

Comment: @BafE. Consider [std::any](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) and [std::variant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) from c++17. You said you would like to avoid them, but they are likely the best option.

Comment: @BafE. if `i` is known at compile-time, it's quite simple. Otherwise, it can't be done cleanly by using the return value, which can only have one type. Are you interested in a solution where you pass in an overloaded functor that receives what would have been the return value ?

Comment: @Quentin yes, i read about functors on other stackoverflow questions, unfortunately i think i didnt understand correctly, i think i have to read up more about functors but definatly interested in the solution. Can the return value then be accessed by reference or would it have to be cast ?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I will fall back on those if I have to. But I am also interested in if what i planned is possible. I would be very happy if i managed even if have to use more convoluted code/structures

Comment: Is there a way to give points to commenters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming the following bare-bones definitions for `MyTuple`:

```
template <class...>
struct MyTuple;

template <class Head, class... Tail>
struct MyTuple<Head, Tail...> : MyTuple<Tail...> {
    Head data;
};

template <class T>
struct MyTuple<T> {
    T data;
};
```

We can take advantage of their recursive nature to define a `get(i)` function on each layer, that will either "return" its `data` if `i == 0`, and pass the call over to the next layer otherwise.

Since we can't (or rather, don't want to) cram N different types into the return value, let's flip the flow control on its head: instead of having `get` return a reference and use it afterwards, we'll pass "use it afterwards" as an overloaded functor to `get`, which will call the correct overload.

```
template <class Head, class... Tail>
struct MyTuple<Head, Tail...> : MyTuple<Tail...> {
    MyTuple<Tail...> &next() {
        return *this;
    }

    template <class F>
    auto get(std::size_t i, F &&f) {
        return i
            ? next().get(i - 1u, std::forward<F>(f))
            : std::forward<F>(f)(data);
    }

    Head data;
};

template <class T>
struct MyTuple<T> {
    template <class F>
    auto get(std::size_t i, F &&f) {
        assert(!i);
        return std::forward<F>(f)(data);
    }

    T data;
};
```

The return value of `get` is the return value of the selected overload. Its type is the *common type* (as `std::common_type` would return) of all of the involved overloads. Using it looks like this:

```
MyTuple<float, int, double> tup;

struct {
    void operator()(float) const { }
    void operator()(int) const { }
    void operator()(double) const { }
} func;

for(std::size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    tup.get(i, func);
```

Each iteration of the loop will call the corresponding overload with the required data.

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/393c970d72a8dd74)

Comment: Thank you @Quentin, just came back home. I still have to wrap my head around this, for example i have to check std::forward and the use of the double ampersand. Also the use of passing these functors is quite interressting and i will read where/which scenario they are most used in. I will up this answer and accept as it seems this is as close as it gets to dynamic access. Can i ask you how long you have been programming in c++? 
Thanks again!

Comment: @BafE. The `&&`/`std::forward` mechanism is called *perfect forwarding*. It allows passing the functor around in the most generic way possible, but is not strictly required (you could just take `F f` by value and call `f(data)` directly if copies aren't an issue). And I've been learning C++ for four years now! Glad to help :)

Comment: I would so call `get` something like `visit_nth` or `apply_nth`

Answer (score 1):

> why does the this work programmatically when i call in source.
>
> ```
> myTuple.next().next();
> ```

Because the type is known at compile time. There are no runtime arguments, like in your `get(int i, int j, OwnType k)` attempt. Your attempt cannot possibly work, but following would be possible to implement:

```
template<class... Ts>
template<std::size_t I>
magic_type& MyTupleImpl<Ts...>::get();
// magic_type is not actual code. It is a
// placeholder for a proper implementation
```

Template arguments are known at compile time, so this can work. Now we must use template magic to figure out the correct type to return. You'll need to use a recursive helper template similar to the following (this example is modified from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_element)):

```
template< std::size_t I, class T >
struct tuple_element;
 
// recursive case
template< std::size_t I, class Head, class... Tail >
struct tuple_element<I, MyTupleImpl<Head, Tail...>>
    : tuple_element<I-1, MyTupleImpl<Tail...>> { };
 
// base case
template< class Head, class... Tail >
struct tuple_element<0, MyTupleImpl<Head, Tail...>> {
   typedef Head type;
};
```

With the help of this, we could declare:

```
template<class... Ts>
template<std::size_t I>
typename tuple_element<I, Ts...>::type&
MyTupleImpl<Ts...>::get();
```

I'll leave the implementation of `MyTupleImpl::get` as an exercise.

Warning: No code in this answer has been tested in any way.

Comment: Ok cool! I will work through your answer, at a glance there seemes to not be a template parameter Index, which means this could be used for dynamic access?

Comment: I will get back to you later tonight, i have to try understand how to implement. Sorry im a bit slow.

Comment: @BafE. the index parameter is named `I` in this code.

Comment: Oh i see, yes, the function return type is tuple_element<I, Ts...>::type&. This is close to the implementation of std::get for std::tuple right?

Comment: @BafE. I copied the implementation of `tuple_element` from cppreference page for `std::tuple_element` and made only minor modifications. I've declared the getter as a member for you, but otherwise the interface is pretty much identical.